# Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

Environment: Windows 11 x64, run CMD as Administrator:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Error

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1105]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to
download and install packages.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))

C:\Windows\System32>
```

[image]

How to install tensorflow by conda success?

Comment: Is there Anaconda software installed in your system? If not, Please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install tensorflow using conda environment and also make sure your system is connected to the internet. Let us know if the issue still persists.